# What are examples of nontrivial principal fiber bundles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, algebraic-groups, principal-bundles

I am looking for an example of $G$ principal fiber bundle over a topological space with $G$ a topological group such that is not trivial. In particular, I would be glad to have an example where G is $PSL(n)$, $SL(n)$ $GL(n)$ or another algebraic linear group with the natural zariski topology.

Comment: Consider something like $G/P$ varying $P$.

Comment: $EG \rightarrow BG$

Comment: Can you extend a little bit? It's always not trivial or do you want give me a hint?

Comment: When you have a group that arises from the symmetries of some algebraic object, it is often the case that principal bundles for that group are in bijective correspondence with locally trivial fiber bundles where the fibers have that algebraic structure. For example, principal $GL(n)$ bundles bijectively correspond to rank n vector bundles. It is not very hard to come up with nontrivial vector bundles (e.g. tautological bundles, tangent bundles for many manifolds, etc.), so these all give rise to nontrivial principal $GL(n)$ bundles.

Comment: Can you suggest a reference for the proof of the last implicati in?

Answer (score 3):

**Question:** "In particular, I would be glad to have an example where G is PSL(n), SL(n) GL(n) or another algebraic linear group with the natural zariski topology."

**Answer:** Let $k$ be the field of complex numbers and let $V:=k\{e_0,e_1\}, V^*:=k\{x_0,x_1\}$. The group $G:=SL(V)$ acts on $V$, and if you let $l:=k\{e_0\}$ be the line spanned by $e_0$ you get a closed subgroup $P\subseteq G$ - the "stabilizer subgroup" of $l$. You may construct the quotient $\pi: G \rightarrow G/P$ and there is an isomorphism

$$G/P \cong \mathbb{P}(V^*) \cong \mathbb{P}^1_k.$$

You may cover $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ by the open subschemes $U_i:=D(x_i)$ and you will find that there is an isomorphism

$$\pi^{-1}(U_i) \cong U_i \times_k P.$$

Hence the map $\pi$ is a locally trivial principal fiber bundle in the Zariski topology with fiber $P$. You get a surjection

$$\pi: SL(V) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(V^*) $$

from an affine scheme $SL(V)$ onto the projective line $\mathbb{P}(V^*)$ with $P$ as "fibers".

**Note:** The reason this is a "fun and interesting" example is the following: All linebundles $L(d):=\mathcal{O}(d)$ on the projective line $C$, has a canonical $SL(V)$-action. This action induce an action on the global sections $H^0(C,L(d)) \cong Sym^d(V^*)$.

$$\rho:SL(V) \rightarrow GL( Sym^d(V^*))$$

And $H^0(C, L(d))$ is an irreducible $SL(V)$-module. Moreover: All finite dimensional irreducible $SL(V)$-modules may be constructed in this way. This is the famous Borel-Weil-Bott formula.

In general if you let $G:=SL(\mathbb{C}^n)$ and $H \subseteq G$ any closed subgroup, you may construct the quotient

$$\pi: G \rightarrow G/H$$

and $G/H$ is a smooth quasiprojective variety of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$. The map $\pi$ is locally trivial in the etale topology. In fact: This type of example was what led people to introduce the "etale topology". If the group $G$ is semi simple and $H$ is parabolic it follows the quotient map $\pi$ is locally trivial in the Zariski topology.